# how to remove image from treeview after added

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, treeview, treenode

Using visual studios 2010 and c# i have a treeview and i added images to each of the nodes. In retrospect i now want to remove the images that are associated with the children of the 3 main root nodes. How do i remove the images from the children of my 3 main root nodes but keep the images on the 3 root nodes?

I have tried opening the properties for the nodes and changed the ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex to "none" for all of the children nodes and when i press ok, it still shows the default image for each child node.

Thanks

Comment: Create a blank icon and add it to the image list.

Comment: @Hans: I am not a big fan of the way that looks. I would prefer i way to remove the image and its "reserved" location. I do not want the words to be offset because of a blank image. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You'll have to use the DrawNode event to get rid of the gap.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific or give an example. I am not seeing how DrawNode is going to help me. There just seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of it, but I believe that you can pass through every control inside the TreeView doing a foreach in [TreeView].Controls... In there you can search for [control].GetType() == typeof([type_of_the_image]), and do some logic to get just the main ones.

Besides that, you can remove by jQuery, doing something close to what I said above. If these ideas are something that interests you, I can help with the development.